# Include Shared Data Source on report?

Tags: xml, reporting-services, bids

I am new to using BIDS and to developing reports in general and I am currently working to add a new report to an existing solution.  My report needs to make sure of a shared data source in the solution so I was just thinking I should copy over the XML used to define the shared data source in the other reports that make use of it and it should be available right? Apparently not..

Another report that makes use of the shared data source has markup like this:

```
<DataSets>
 <DataSet Name="sharedDataSetName">
  <SharedDataSet>
    <SharedDataSetReference>sharedDataSetName</SharedDataSetReference>
    <QueryParameters>
      <QueryParameter Name="@user_name">
        <Value>=Parameters!username.Value</Value>
      </QueryParameter>
    </QueryParameters>
  </SharedDataSet>
  <Fields>
   ...
```

But when I go to enter the XML markup into the report I am developing, I get an error when I get to:

```
<DataSets>
  <DataSet Name="sharedDataSetname">
    <SharedDataSet>
```

Saying that the element in namespace "namespace..." has invalid child element `<SharedDataSet>`.  How can this be if the other reports make use of that child element??

NOTE: When I open sql server business intelligence development studio it opens Microsoft Visual Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay first of all why are you looking at the xml directly?  In a BIDS solution you should see at least one project for SSRS.  That project should have three folders:

1. Shared Data Sources
2. Shared Data Sets
3. Reports

If you are trying to do ANYTHING directly in the XML you should be asking why you are doing that.  Generally you double click the Shared Data Sources under the project and it has a friendly window to set settings on.  If you have another report referencing that data source in your report the main window SSRS developers work with is 'Report Data'.  If you can't find it in BIDS go to 'View' and it should be near the bottom.  Under Data Sources folder IN report data right click > Add Data Source > select 'Use Shared Data Source Reference' any data sources set in ONLY THAT PROJECT will be there.  If you are trying to reference a shared datasource in another project you have to add it again with all the same settings.

Comment: I have a solution explorer window with the three folders you mentioned, a properties window below that, the output window at the bottom, a toolbox window on the left, and in the middle are the reports that I have open.  I don't see a 'Report Data' under 'View' anywhere; only: code, designer, open, server explorer, solution explorer, bookmark window, class view, code definition window, object browser, error list, output, properties window, task list, toolbox, find results (arrow), other windows (arrow not in there), toolbars (arrow),  and fullscreen.  No 'Report Data'.

Comment: And I want to say it was a typo in your post but I'm not trying to add a shared data source, I'm trying to add a shared data set.

Comment: I suppose it could make a difference that when I open sql server business intelligence development studio it opens Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: Which Version of BIDS are you using?  It may already be tabbed on the side.  You must be in a report to see it.  If it is already tabbed somewhere it won't show in View.  If it is not it will to be able to enable it from the view but only when you are in designer in a report.

Comment: That's what it was, I was still in the XML code for the report, once I clicked back to designer for the report I could see it in View.  Thank you

Comment: Sounds good.  Keep in mind with SSRS as you learn it there are three main parts for the creating of reports as I listed above.  Try not to look at the xml directly till you get more of a feeling for SSRS or it will make it more confusing IMHO.